# Wireshark - Browser software

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, wireshark

I just touched wireshark yesterday from my class. I was told to run wireshark while browsing www.kompas.com, and there is this question that is quite ambiguous.

"What browser software shown in wireshark screen?"

Does the question asks me what is the server's web browser is running? Does wireshark capable of doing that? Because when I follow the TCP stream from the website, it shows only my browser software.

Comment: So I assume this wasn’t an English question, right? Could you please share the exact question in its “native” language?

Comment: That is the exact same question that my lecturer gave to me. He gave it to me in english also. The second question is "What server software and version the web server is using?". But I think i get what the second question asks me. But i do not seem to understand the first one. I am sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser software for sure refers to the client aka your computer. If you run Firefox, and find the corresponding Firefox version in your Wireshark output, you're good.

Your second question is the question for the server's Web server software, and you should find that information in the same TCP stream.

Comment: Thank you for clearing up. However, is wireshark capabel of giving the web server's browser software? I am sorry if it is a stupid question, but I'm just curious

Comment: Yes, it is capable as most web servers report their own version information by default when sending you a reply. You may find a HTTP header like "Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.6 PHP/5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2 with Suhosin-Patch proxy_html/3.0.1 mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.7.1+"